# Strange behaviour with text inside HTML and MigLayout

Tags: java, miglayout

I'm trying to get used to `MigLayout` and I can't figure out this problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel htmlLabel = new JLabel();

    panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    htmlLabel.setText(""); // This is where I put my text.

    panel.add(htmlLabel);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setMaximumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

So with this example, if I do

1. `htmlLabel.setText("Some TEXT")`
2. `htmlLabel.setText("Some LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG TEXT");`
3. If I do the same as #2 but add `<html></html>` around the text i.e. `htmlLabel.setText("<html>Some LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG TEXT</html>")`
4. Same as #3 but I set `BoxLayout` to the panel. i.e. `panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));`

## Results

1. I get [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXobJ.png)
2. I get [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EwAc.png)
3. I get [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1cJ6.png)
4. I get [this as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8LYk.png)

So what's wrong with #3? Why does `MigLayout` center the text like that as the text grows but just when inside `html` tag?

NOTE: I know `html` tag will make the text wrap but it shouldn't move to the center...

## Solution

After trying Charles Knell's answer, it worked. Just an update on how to do it with `MigLayout`. I add my label to the layout like this:

`add(helpLabel, "grow")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the html tag is a very unconventional way.

That might explain why you seem to get some unexpected results.

The minimum that you need, tag wise, is

```
<html><body><p>your content</p></body></html>
```

see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp

I ran your code as follows and it works perfectly:

```
package htmlmiglayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class HTMLMigLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //new
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel htmlLabel = new JLabel();

    panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    htmlLabel.setText("<html><body><p>Some LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG TEXT</p></body></html>"); // This is where I put my text.

    panel.add(htmlLabel);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setMaximumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image: The above code generates the following window:]

However, if I use different label dimensions and set the alignment so that the top of the text begins at the top of the label, I can reproduce your output.

Here is the modified code:

```
package htmlmiglayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.*;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class HTMLMigLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //new
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel htmlLabel = new JLabel();
    htmlLabel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300,95));
    htmlLabel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,95));
    htmlLabel.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);

    panel.setLayout(new MigLayout());
    htmlLabel.setText("<html><body><p>Some LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG LONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNG TEXT</p></body></html>"); // This is where I put my text.

    panel.add(htmlLabel);

    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    frame.setMinimumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setMaximumSize(frame.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

and here is the output

[image]

So, You are getting default JLabel dimensions which don't allow for displaying the end of the string.

Comment: I tried your code and I still get the [same behaviour.](http://i.imgur.com/ZMV6bmO.png) And I don't think you need the `<body>` tag in java. [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)

Comment: I've edited my answer to account for showing that the problem is caused by the default dimensions of your label.

Comment: That's a weird behaviour but it looks like it's kind of working. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I believe your html tags are defining a border around the page, and your "long text" is reaching that border, creating a new line by the space.

It's the same way when writing text. If you reach the near the end of a line, then have a word that's longer than the character limit per line, it doesn't do a hyphen, similar to the way books do. It will start a new line, continuing the word.

My reasoning behind this? The text starts a bit off the left side of the page, yet doesn't reach the very end of the same line. It's not symmetrical.

I don't have experience in MigLayout, but I believe this may be what's causing the distortion between the text from using the html tags vs not using them.

Comment: Even if I do `htmlLabel.setText("<html>1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1</html>")` I get the same result.

Comment: Hm, that is odd. Why not just wrap it with <p></p> or <h1></h1> elements? That way, you secure that it'll stay on the same line. And if it doesn't, then I'd be surprised.

Comment: Actually the problem came when I tried to use a numbered list `<ol><li></li></ol>`. Then I tried to isolate the problem hence the simple code. I tried putting the text inside `<p></p>` I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in MigLayout (https://github.com/mikaelgrev/miglayout/issues/41). It's a regression in 5.0 and will be fixed in the next release (current release as of May 2018 is 5.1).

dguay's workaround works well if it's okay to grow the HTML `JLabel`.